# EF could not translate expression to sql

Tags: sql, entity-framework, expression

It looks like EF is not able to translate the express in the following code, this is the call

```
Counter lastCounter = unitOfWork.CounterRepository.FindLast(x => x.Div == counter.Div, x => x.Div);
```

this is the method

```
    public Counter FindLast(Expression<Func<Counter, bool>> predicate, params Expression<Func<Counter, object>>[] includedProperties)
    {
        IQueryable<Counter> set = context.Set<Counter>().Where(predicate);

        foreach (var includeProperty in includedProperties)
        {
            set = set.Include(includeProperty);
        }
        return set.Last();
    }
```

Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Is there any exception or result returns empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite simple, really: Entity Framework just does not support `Last().` The reason for this is that in SQL, you also cannot select the last element (i.e. you have `SELECT TOP` but don't have `SELECT BOTTOM`).

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/supported-and-unsupported-linq-methods-linq-to-entities

Comment: yes, but they can sort descending then select Top, right?

Comment: I guess they could do that, but then comes the question: sort descending by what? I guess that they could do a sort just based on the PK, but I suspect there are some other design questions that this solution would pose. But if you want, you can do that yourself explicitly in your query.